# C# Installer's call to a different exe does not work

Tags: c#, windows, process, cmd, installation

I have an installer (`installer.exe`) that calls off to another installer (`subinstaller.exe`).  This is how I trigger the other installer:

```
public void Run(String commandName, params String[] args)
{
    var commandProcess = new Process();

    commandProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    commandProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    commandProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    commandProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    commandProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    commandProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    commandProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

    var arguments = String.Join(" ", args);
    var command = String.Format("/C \"\"{0}\" {1}\"", commandName, arguments);
    commandProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = command;

    using (commandProcess)
    {
        commandProcess.Start();

        var errors = commandProcess.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(errors) == false)
        {
            var message = String.Format("A problem occurred while running \"{0}\": {1}", command, errors);
            throw new Exception(message);
        }

        commandProcess.WaitForExit();
    }
}
```

The command that is causing me trouble ends up being the following:

```
cmd.exe /C ""C:\Updater\subinstaller.exe" /norestart /silent /serial="TRIAL""
```

If I run that command in a command prompt, everything works as expected.  However, if I run it via the process as described above (where `commandName` is `C:\Updater\subinstaller.exe`), then it does not run properly.  I would assume this is because of a permission issue, but I have effectively ruled that out:

1. My highest-level installer is running as admin via a manifest requiring elevated permissions.  I have individually verified that the `cmd.exe` process that is kicked off runs under the same elevated permissions.
2. I have explicitly had it run under both SYSTEM and a local admin account, both of which also did not work.

I really am running out of ideas on what could be causing the problem.  Considering that it works in raw command-line, it is very unlikely to be the sub-installer.  Does anyone have any ideas?

**UPDATE**

I have also tried taking `cmd` out of the equation:

```
public void Run(String commandName, params String[] args)
{
    var commandProcess = new Process();

    commandProcess.StartInfo.FileName = commandName;
    commandProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    commandProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    commandProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    commandProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    commandProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    commandProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

    var arguments = String.Join(" ", args);
    commandProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;

    using (commandProcess)
    {
        commandProcess.Start();

        var errors = commandProcess.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(errors) == false)
        {
            var message = String.Format("A problem occurred while running \"{0}\": {1}", commandName, errors);
            throw new Exception(message);
        }

        commandProcess.WaitForExit();

        if (commandProcess.ExitCode != 0)
        {
            var message = String.Format("A problem occurred while running \"{0}\": Exit code {1}", commandName, commandProcess.ExitCode);
            throw new Exception(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does putting it in a try catch show any exceptions? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No errors to speak of.  My hand-rolled exception is never thrown (so no command line errors), and this method is already wrapped in a try-catch, and that records no errors either.

Comment: Have you checked commandProcess.ExitCode after the process has exited?  A non-zero ExitCode may give you some indication about what's going wrong.

Comment: Have you try directly calling subinstaller.exe instead of calling cmd.exe first?

Comment: @JosBosmans Yes, I have checked the exit code.  It is 0.

Comment: @currarpickt - yes.  The command was original done as a way to solve the permission problem.  Undoing that and calling the subinstaller directly still produces the same problem.

Comment: how do you know the installer is not run properly if there is no errors?

Comment: @currarpickt - if the installer runs properly, then certain licensing information is altered in the registry.  When you run them in command-line, that happens correctly.  When my installer runs the commands for the subinstaller, those registry entries become blank - which indicates a permission/write error to the registry